# How to convert cross tables to lists in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how we can use vba to convert the table on the range "A1:C4" to the one on "F1:H6" as shown in the following picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCpWE.png

Thanks

Comment: No vba needed, use the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Thank you its exactly what I was looking for